# How to do a count on table's <tr> and make some andother background-color in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, count, html-table

In ASP.net I'm having this in the frontend, and in the backend(vb) I want to do a count on all `<tr>`'s on this page and every other (so the 2nd, 4th, 6th,...)  has to have another background color.

How do I count all `<tr>`'s on a page and how can tell them to give every other one another background-color?

This is the frontend:

```
<p class="title"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Title 1"></asp:Label></p>
     <table class="table">
        <tr><td>Person 1</td><td>Bestuurder</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Person 2</td><td>Zaakvoerder</td></tr>
    </table>

    <p class="title"><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Title 2"></asp:Label></p>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_add_beheerder" runat="server" Text="BEHEERDER TOEVOEGEN" class="btn_add"/>
     <table class="table">
        <tr><td>Person 3</td><td>Beheerder</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Person 4</td><td>Beheerder</td></tr>
    </table>
```

The backend is just going to be on a page_load.
I think the best way to do this is putting every `<tr>` in an array and then every `array[i]` that's dividable by 2 give another background-color? 
Is this the best way to work?

Answer (score 0):

you could of course do this in a gazillion different ways.
Here just one suggestion.

```
<asp:GridView id="gv" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Person" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Something else"/>
            </Columns>
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Blue" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="ds"
            ConnectionString="your connectionString"
            SelectCommand="--select stuff">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

note the "AlternatingRowStyle"

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your css class should be enough

```
.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: silver;
}
```

if you are working with dynamically generated table then add the css class attribute

```
HtmlTable myTable = new HtmlTable();
// initialization
myTable.Attributes.Add("Class", "table");
```